# how to save reports to a pdf file in java desktop application?

Tags: java, pdf, report

I am developing a java desktop application, a management system to be precise.I have a reports function that populates the product reports to jtables. I want to save those reports to a pdf file when someone presses the reports button.Can anyone help me in this? Than you.

Comment: There are lot of libraries available for PDF creation. Please make a search in google. JasperReports, PDFBox etc.. Your question is too broad.

Comment: JasperReports looks good to me

Comment: Here's a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6YwDME0Fl1c) and here's a [free ebook](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html) so that you can get some inspiration. In any case: your question is off-topic, because you are asking to recommend a tool and that's not what StackOverflow is for.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Apache PDFBox. Check out sample programs on google